# send fake ip address for defined ip for security

Tags: security, ip, vpn

I need to send a fake IP address to a defined server (ip) due to the need for security and distrust in that server. Unfortunately, I have to use this server, but I do not want fake IP to be sent to all servers where I connect. I need it for windows operating system.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by send a fake IP? Like, you enter a URL in your web browser, and when the browser connects to the remote site, it appears to the remote site that request comes from a different IP than your own?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am connecting to a server that has an IP and I am connecting from my IP, I need to somehow set it up to connect to a given server that has an IP from an IP other than mine. But I need it to connect to the server I choose under a fake IP. So I can't use a normal VPN that connects to all the servers I go to.